# Oracle SQL: How do I find the table name given the column names?

Tags: sql, oracle

If I know the names of every column of a table but not the name of the table, how do I find the name of the table I need?

Comment: Not sure but if the primary key column_names for every table is unique then you can maybe try accessing the meta-data of the database and searching through the tables?

Answer (score 15):

Based on @Roobie's solution, the code below searches in all schemas you have access to, in case the table is not in your own schema.  Also added case-insensitive matching.

```
SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM all_tab_columns
  WHERE UPPER(column_name) = UPPER('MYCOL');
```

Comment: Hey Josh, nice editing. I think you don't need UPPER on the left hand side (UPPER(column_name)). Cheers!

Comment: @Roobie, 99.8% of the time, but there's always the possibility of bat stuff crazy vendor code (thinking of an app designed for SQL Server that the vendor made an Oracle version).  You can create mixed case columns in Oracle, though you shouldn't.  Example:  `CREATE TABLE stupid_table ( "MixedCaseColumn" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY );` .  Putting `UPPER` on both sides covers your butt for nearly 100% of cases.  For a good laugh, see this fiddle I just put together: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2840e/1/0

Answer (score 10):

Try this (one known column):

`CREATE TABLE mytab(mycol VARCHAR2(30 CHAR));`
`SELECT table_name FROM user_tab_columns WHERE column_name='MYCOL';`

Note `MYCOL` is in *upper* case in `column_name='MYCOL'`;

Cheers!

Comment: There are other views available as well: USER_TAB_COLS,
ALL_TAB_COLS, ALL_TAB_COLUMNS. Depending on your access privileges, these are also available: DBA_TAB_COLS, DBA_TAB_COLUMNS

Answer (score -4):

```
select * from all_updatable_columns where column_name like 'reqd col name';
```